# React app working on localhost but giving error when deployed either on github or on heroku. No error while deploying

Tags: reactjs, heroku, web-deployment

I create a react app to show corona infection in different countries. This work on my localhost but when i deploy it either on github or on heroku a error generated. below error is given in blockquote. Looking at error when i check file **country.js** there is no **n[0]**. please help below is link to hosted app and github repository of the app.

> TypeError: "n[0] is undefined"
>       E country.js:13
>       E country.js:11
>       React 7
>       unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.production.min.js:19
>       React 6
>       a App.js:22
>       u runtime.js:45
>       _invoke runtime.js:274
>       t runtime.js:97
>       r asyncToGenerator.js:3
>       a asyncToGenerator.js:25
>   react-dom.production.min.js:209:194
>       React 5
>       unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.production.min.js:19
>       React 4
>       unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.production.min.js:19
>       React 6
>       a App.js:22
>       u runtime.js:45
>       _invoke runtime.js:274
>       t runtime.js:97
>       r asyncToGenerator.js:3
>       a asyncToGenerator.js:25
>   TypeError: n[0] is undefined
>   country.js:13:30

​
[this is link to hosted app on heroku](https://corona-infection-tracker.herokuapp.com/)
and
[this is link to app hosted on Github](https://satishchandra538.github.io/corona-tracker/)

> [This is github repository](https://github.com/satishchandra538/corona-tracker)

Comment: Error - Cannot read property 'Afghanistan' of undefined. Country.js line 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [stated by Dishant Desai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60924993/6151167), it is giving a TypeError. In order to fix it, 
you can change the code in `country.js` from

```
const countryflag = Object.keys(data).map((name) => {
    return data[name][0];
})
```

to

```
const countryflag = data[0];
```

And use it directly this way:

```
${countryflag[country[0]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your site and it gives the following error:

```
react_devtools_backend.js:6 TypeError: Cannot read property 'Afghanistan' of undefined
    at country.js:13
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at E (country.js:11)
    at Ki (react-dom.production.min.js:153)
    at Fo (react-dom.production.min.js:175)
    at va (react-dom.production.min.js:263)
    at cu (react-dom.production.min.js:246)
    at au (react-dom.production.min.js:246)
    at Za (react-dom.production.min.js:239)
    at react-dom.production.min.js:123
```

So for that, you have to share the code of that file.

Comment: link of github repository is given in the question and (https://github.com/satishchandra538/corona-tracker/blob/master/src/country.js) is link of country.js

Comment: This is working fine on my PC when i run it on local host but when it is deployed on Github its not working properly and that error is generating.